# macOS: What's the correct place to install a dylib on a user's system?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, dylib

I've developing a software package that needs to install a dylib somewhere globally accessible by all user accounts. I'm not actually sure where the best place to put it is.

Ordinarily I would think `/usr/local/lib` is correct, but occasionally we encounter users who do strange things with that folder, including changing its permissions so that only one user can access the files in it, thus breaking my software for other user accounts on that system. Technically this sort of thing isn't disallowed on macOS -- `/usr/local` is intended to be a place that the user can utilize however they like.

An alternative solution could be in either `/Library/Frameworks` or `/Library/Application Support/<my app name>`. Those folders would certainly be safer as users are **not** supposed to use them however they want, nor modify their permissions. However neither place strikes me as correct for a dynamic library. `/Library/Frameworks` comes the closest and I think I've encountered other apps that put dylibs in there, but it's obviously intended for frameworks.

So where's the correct place to put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mac is a bit of a strange beast when it comes to file system locations, and it's going to get more difficult after macOS 10.15 (Catalina) ships, due to the primary boot file system being read-only.

Depending on the purpose of accessing the library, there are some appropriate places to put it.

### In your Application bundle

If you have an Application that is being installed globally in the `/Applications` folder (most Applications are on the Mac, but sometimes users put them in strange places), then you could use the Application's own folder for storage of the library and it would be available to any code that can read in that folder. There are a number of problems with this, though: the user can move the Application, permissions may be wrong, and you have to be careful in any code that uses the Apple Hardened Runtime because it requires special flags to load code signed by anyone other than the signatory on the Application loading the library. The advantage is that deleting the Application also deletes your library, so you don't need to write an uninstaller. This technique is used by software like VMWare Fusion (if you need to run command-line code or similar) and

### /Library/Application Support or /Library/Frameworks

If you need the library to be persistent and guaranteed to be in one clearly-defined location, then having the User approve your installation into `/Library/Application Support/<your application>` or into `/Library/Frameworks` is likely your best bet.

### /usr/local/lib

As you've already noticed, `/usr/local/lib` can be problematic, especially since the popular [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) package manager generally sets the `/usr/local/lib` to be owned by the user installing files with brew so that it can be modified without needing to `sudo`.

With that said, though, you can install in `/usr/local/lib`, with the proviso that you may need to escalate privileges in order to perform the installation. Once the installation is done, the directory is usually set to be readable by any other user on the system.

### Recommendation

As a long-time Mac user, I prefer when Applications keep themselves contained (codewise) to their Application bundle, and thus would encourage using that mechanism.  The downside of the user not installing in `/Applications` can be mitigated by having the Application itself check when it runs to make sure that it's in the right place, and if not, prompt the user to move it (or do the moving after asking for a privilege elevation).  This also removes the need for an installer/uninstaller program.

If that's not acceptable for some reason, then the `/Library/Frameworks` or `/Library/Application Support/<your application>` would be your next best bet.  They're much less likely to create a problem than `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: AFAIK an app will crash before it gets a chance to check its path, if it references a dylib by an absolute path at which said lib doesn't exist. But there is `@rpath`, see `man dyld`.

Comment: That’s completely dependent upon how you load the dylib.  If you are having people depend on something you install, that’s going to always be a risk if you don’t pre-flight or manually load it.

Comment: I was saying that if you have an app bundle within which you ship a dylib that you normally link against, your suggestion of checking for execution path will not work, as the app will have crashed at launch already. However you can do away with the check altogether and go path-independent by using `@rpath` instead of an absolute name when building/linking the dylib, allowing the app to be self-contained without any issues or path constraints.

Comment: @Siguza Certainly. Maybe I’m missing what he’s trying to do. If this is a dylib that is going to be used by the App, then it belongs in the App bundle itself.  That’s the best way to handle shared libraries that are used by the Application itself.  My interpretation of the OP was that they were shipping a .dylib that needed to be accessed by (other applications or binaries) that would be run by other users on the user’s system. If other applications or binaries need to use those libraries, either they must be weak linked or they will crash. Weak linking has been used for a long time on the Mac